# Un-TAR and un-GZip file stored as JavaScript Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, tar, multer

I am developing a server script on Node.js/Express.js that receives uploaded .tar.gz archives with multiple files. The script has to untar and ungzip CSV files in archives, parse them and store some in database. There is no need to store files on the server, just process them. To upload files I am using Multer without specifying where to store files, so file uploads are only available in `req.files` as `Buffer`.

My question is, how is it possible to untar and ungzip Buffer to get the contents of the files?
If I do something like:

```
const { unzipSync } = require('zlib');

const zipped = req.files[0];
const result = await unzipSync(zipped.buffer);
const str = result.toString('utf-8');
```

I get not the content of the file, but all information including file name, some metadata etc as string, which is tricky to parse. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use actual `tar` and then load in the resulting data from disk? (using `exec` or `spawn`)

Comment: Yeah, or even easier to use tar module for Node, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar. I was just thinking if I can avoid saving upload to the disk and untar from Buffer itself.

Comment: If you want to unpack a tgz, you need to both unzip _and_ untar. Right now you're only unzipping.

Comment: Yes. But how to untar Buffer in JavaScript? I've found many modules but without such functionality. They mostly work with files in file system or reading streams.

Comment: you literally link to a library that does what you need, but you can't find a specific detail, so: you probably want to [ask for them to document how to do that on their issue tracker](https://github.com/npm/node-tar/issues). That way, everyone in the open source community benefits.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to untar and unzip Buffer using [tar-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar-stream) and [streamifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamifier) libraries.

```
const tar = require('tar-stream');
const streamifier = require('streamifier');
const { unzipSync } = require('zlib');

const untar = ({ buffer }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Buffer is representation of .tar.gz file uploaded to Express.js server
  // using Multer middleware with MemoryStorage
  const textData = [];
  const extract = tar.extract();
  // Extract method accepts each tarred file as entry, separating header and stream of contents:
  extract.on('entry', (header, stream, next) => {
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    stream.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
    stream.on('end', () => {
      // We concatenate chunks of the stream into string and push it to array, which holds contents of each file in .tar.gz:
      const text = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8');
      textData.push(text);
      next();
    });
    stream.resume();
  });
  extract.on('finish', () => {
    // We return array of tarred files's contents:
    resolve(textData);
  });
  // We unzip buffer and convert it to Readable Stream and then pass to tar-stream's extract method:
  streamifier.createReadStream(unzipSync(buffer)).pipe(extract);
});
```

Using this approach I managed to avoid storing any temporary files on filesystem and process all files' contents in memory exclusively.